# Python webscraping, Spotify webplayer, issues with scrolling to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I want to make a python program that when given a link to a Spotify playlist will return a list of the track names. This is what I have so far.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url="https://open.spotify.com/playlist/1xXEN6UhQEMsVhX4KitlhW"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

page = driver.page_source
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

tracks = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"tracklist-name"})

print(tracks)
print(len(tracks))

driver.close()
```

However this only returns the first 100 songs. I have discovered that typing `document.getElementsByClassName("tracklist-name")` into the developer console in browser will also only return the first 100 songs, unless I have scrolled to the bottom of the page, so I want to scroll to the bottom of the page first but `window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)` does not work because the playlist isn't in the main body, the actual body of the page cannot be scrolled at all (I don't know all the technical terms I am a newbie at Javascript).

So how would I write a script that scrolls to the bottom of the Spotify playlist such that I can extract all the songs, not just the first 100?

Comment: Spotify provides an API: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/get-playlist

Comment: Can’t you use the spotify API for this? In any case, have you checked to see if you could make the same requests as they do, instead of having to rely on Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer using scrolling, but you can get the data direct from the Spotify api:

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/get-playlists-tracks/

Note that you can only get up to 100 track titles at a time, so you will have to make multiple requests and use the offset parameter. This is also why your browser only loads 100 songs at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Spotify API requires you register for a license which is a bit over the top for just a little project I'm working on, I however have managed to bodge this script together that works. If anyone in the future sees this post hoping to do a similar project to me, please do not copy this code. It is terrible.

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver

url="https://open.spotify.com/playlist/1xXEN6UhQEMsVhX4KitlhW"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

cont = False
previousScrollHeight = 0

while cont == False:
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.execute_script("var HTMLCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('main-view-container__scroll-node'); var objDiv = HTMLCollection[0]; objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;")
    scrollTop = driver.execute_script("var HTMLCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('main-view-container__scroll-node'); var objDiv = HTMLCollection[0]; return objDiv.scrollTop;")

    time.sleep(1)
    scrollHeight = driver.execute_script("var HTMLCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('main-view-container__scroll-node'); var objDiv = HTMLCollection[0]; return objDiv.scrollHeight;")

    if previousScrollHeight == scrollHeight:
        cont = True

    previousScrollHeight = scrollHeight


tracks = driver.execute_script("obj = document.getElementsByClassName('tracklist-name'); var lst = []; for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { lst.push(obj[i].innerText) }; return lst;")
artists = driver.execute_script("obj = document.getElementsByClassName('TrackListRow__artists'); var lst = []; for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { lst.push(obj[i].innerText) }; return lst;")

driver.close()

zipped = zip(tracks, artists)
print(list(zipped))
```